# How can I deploy a Liberty application with server.xml using Bluemix devOps service

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, devops

I have a Java Web application that I want to deploy to Bluemix's Cloud Foundry runtime. I'd like to run it on the Liberty application server and customize the server configuration with the server.xml file. I know how to do this in the CLI with a server package or server directory, but how do I complete this task using the Bluemix DevOps service? By default, it only pushes the WAR package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done in this way:

1. Put the customized server.xml and jvm.options files in a sub-folder like "defaultServer";
2. Modify your build script to create a zip file with below structure:

   ```
    |- server.xml
    |- jvm.options
    |- apps
       |- myapp.war
   ```
3. Modify the manifest.yml file of the project to specify the path to be the zip file created in Step 2.

Note the server.xml need to define a web app that points to the WAR, for example:

```
  <webApplication id="myapp" location="myapp.war" name="myapp" context-root="/" />
```

Comment: I am using maven to build with devOps, how can I "Modify your build script to create a zip file with below structure" in this case?